# Mapping a list in flutter

Tags: list, flutter, dart, mobile, mapping

I tried mapping a list of Question to a widget and it keep trowing back error when i run the app but no error warnings in the code. Please can someone help me detect what am doing wrong here.

```
...(questions[_questionIndex]['answer'] as List<String>).map((answer) {
              return Answer(_answerQuestion, answer);
            }).toList(),
```

from the code above am calling a question list with index of _questionIndex which is generated by the length of all the questions and then accessing a key with the name 'answer'. please the list is a list of maps of question and answers.

and here is my error in app:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following _CastError was thrown building MyApp(dirty, state: _MyAppState#38d02):
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>' in type cast
```

Comment: Can you add a sample data of `questions[_questionIndex]['answer']` ?

Comment: "no error warnings in code" ... There will not be any static analysis errors because you explicitly suppressed them by performing the explicit `as List<String>` cast.  When you do that, you're telling the analyzer and compiler to trust you.

Answer (score 0):

`questions[_questionIndex]['answer']` contains a null value, and you're casting it to a non-nullable `List<String>`. Either ensure that the iterable does not contain any `null` values, or change your casting to `List<String?>` to allow for null values.

Comment: questions[_questionIndex]['answer'] actualy contains a list of answers and is definatly not null, dart saying its null is getting me confused.

Comment: Change your cast to `List<String?>` and try it. Otherwise, you need to provide some sample data so I can see it.

Comment: Thanks for all your contributions. I found the error it was a typo when i called the value from the Map.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your contributions. I found the error it was a typo when i called the value from the Map.